# Three numbered equations all on the same line

Tags: equations, subequations

I have three numbered equations, and after typing them, I realized I would rather have them all on the same line.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    C_t =&\: \frac{C_\alpha C_\beta}{\sqrt{3}}\label{eqn:3-5a}\\
    C_y =&\: \frac{C_\alpha C_\gamma}{\sqrt{3}}\label{eqn:3-5b}\\
    C_r =&\: \frac{C_\alpha C_\delta}{\sqrt{3}}\label{eqn:3-5c}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

But now I don't like this and would prefer these equations all be on a single line, with a space in-between, and the numbers on the right are just (3.5a,b,c). **How would I go about doing this?** I see things like this in textbooks, so I know it's not unheard of.

[image: Equations]

Comment: note `&=` rather than `=&` then you would not need to add extra space

Comment: If you're referring to the horizontal spacing, I don't need it; that's what I want.

Comment: `align` is designed for `&=` you can use `=&` for special cases but you need to correct the space in that case. `\:` is an approximation to that. But whatever, as you want them all on same line the issue goes anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    C_t = \frac{C_\alpha C_\beta}{\sqrt{3}}\qquad
    C_y = \frac{C_\alpha C_\gamma}{\sqrt{3}}\qquad
    C_r = \frac{C_\alpha C_\delta}{\sqrt{3}}
    \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation\,a,b,c}\label{eqn:avoidnumbers}
\end{equation}

aaa \eqref{eqn:avoidnumbers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `eqref` referring to?

Comment: @WnGatRC456 `\eqref` is a standard amsmath command, essentially `\ref` but adds same () as used in the equation. I changed the `\label` as it is best to avoid numeric labels like `\label{eqn:3-5c}`

Comment: I see, thank you. This is helpful.